# Knockout click event binding sending wrong data

Tags: html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
   vm.icdCodes.push({Index:i, ID:'',DiagnosisCd: '' ,Description:ko.observable('')});
}

   <tbody data-bind='foreach: $root.icdCodes'>
       <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="text" class="icdCodeInput" list="icdcodes" data-bind="value: DiagnosisCd, event: { focusout: $root.dxCodeLostFocus}, attr: { id: 'icdCodeInput' + $index() }">
            <datalist id="icdcodes" class="icdcodes">
            </datalist>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"  data-bind=" click:    $root.moveDxCodeUp, attr: { id: 'dxCodeUpButton' + $index() }">
            <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>


 vm.moveDxCodeUp = function (data) {
        if (data.DiagnosisCd != "")
        {
            var currentDxCode = data;
            var previousDxCode = vm.icdCodes()[data.Index - 1];
            if (currentDxCode.Index > 0)
            {
                vm.icdCodes()[data.Index - 1] = currentDxCode;
                vm.icdCodes()[data.Index] = previousDxCode;

                var tempIndex = currentDxCode.Index;
                currentDxCode.Index = previousDxCode.Index;
                previousDxCode.Index = tempIndex;
            }
        }
```

In my HTML I am looping within icdCodes observable array to add few HTML 5 datalist and adjacent buttons alongside it. The button when clicked allows me to move the value in the current textbox into the textbox which is above it. The first time I click the button, the values gets interchanged properly. But if I hit the button again, the data parameter in the movedxCodeUp function still gets the original value (before the interchange) and not the value which got interchanged after hitting the button. I am also interchanging the values in the actual observable collection (icdCodes) in the function.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle repro? Your code is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/JVahL/1/

Comment: The only difference between my code and yours is that you have added one line vm.icdCodes.valueHasMutated(). I am not adding it. This may be the reason, I am getting the old value after the values interchange. I will add that line and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: vm.icdCodes.valueHasMutated() did the trick. Thank you. Since, icdCodes is an observable array, why we need to call the valueHasMutated function explicitly on it ? You can change your comment to answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your `icdCodes` is a `ko.observableArray` becuase you are directly manipulating the underlying array to swap your items KO won't be notified about this changes so it doesn't re-render the view.

To make it work you just need to call the `valueHasMutated` function which notifies KO that your array has changed:

```
vm.icdCodes()[data.Index - 1] = currentDxCode;
vm.icdCodes()[data.Index] = previousDxCode;
vm.icdCodes.valueHasMutated();
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVahL/1/).